# Instanciar método desde otra clase en C#

Tags: c#

Este es el código en el form

```
private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Conexion c = new Conexion();


        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = mostrarEquipo();
        this.dataGridView1.DataMember = "xxx";

        mostrarTipo();

        this.cbotipo.DataSource = datos.Tables["xxx"];
        this.cbotipo.ValueMember = "COD_TIPO_EQUIPO";
        this.cbotipo.DisplayMember = "DESCRIPCION";

        mostrarEstado();

        this.cboestado.DataSource = datos.Tables["xxx"];
        this.cboestado.ValueMember = "CODESTADO";
        this.cboestado.DisplayMember = "DESCRIPCION";

    }
```

Y este en la clase conexion.cs

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexion"].ConnectionString);
    DataSet datos;

    DataSet mostrarEquipo()
    {
        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter("spListar_Equipo", con);
        datos = new DataSet();
        ad.Fill(datos, "xxx");

        return datos;
    }

    DataSet mostrarTipo()
    {
        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter("spListar_Tipo", con);
        datos = new DataSet();
        ad.Fill(datos, "xxx");

        return datos;
    }

    DataSet mostrarEstado()
    {
        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter("spListar_Estado", con);
        datos = new DataSet();
        ad.Fill(datos, "xxx");

        return datos;
    }
```

Lo que quiero es llamar esos métodos de la clase conexion.cs desde el Form1_Load_1, instancié la conección y todo Ok pero noce cómo llamar los métodos ya que me sale error: "...No existe en el contexto actual"

Comment: Aparte de tu problema específico, te aviso que no estás cerrando la conexión en ninguna parte, por lo que pareces tener un *resource leak* parcial, o sea que dependes del *garbage collector* para cerrar las conexiones. Eso no está bien. Yo revisiaría el diseño de tu clase `conexion.cs`. Generalmente no es buena idea trabajar con una variable global para una conexión a la base de datos. De hecho, tampoco me parece normal que las llamadas a tus SP estén en una clase llamada `conexion.cs`, pero bueno..

Comment: En realidad hice la coneccion en el App.config, los métodos y llamadas a los SP en el propio form1.cs
Quería ver si hacía la coneccion y métodos en un clase aparte y en el form solo llamarlos

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que corregir por lo menos 2 cosas:

1. Debes modificar los métodos para que sean públicos. Ejemplo:

   ```
   public DataSet mostrarEquipo()
   ```
2. Debes calificar los accesos a estos métodos usando la instancia `c`, porque los métodos le pertenecen. Ejemplo:

   ```
   c.mostrarTipo();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Si estas trabajando en monocapa y quieres utilizar el metodo de una clase.

la clase debe ser publica : public class conexion()

el metodo tambien debe ser declarado como publica : public dataset MostrarTipo()

entonces de tu formularios lo llamarias de esta forma: conexion.MostrarTipo();